# Magento cart rule buy x and y get $ off

Tags: magento-1.8, cart-rule

I'm trying to create this cart rules without real success.
I will need some help.

1/ Buy x + y get $50 off
This means that you can buy 2x + 2y and get $100 off
Or buy 2x + 1y and get $50 off...

2/ Buy x + y + z get $75 off
If you remove z from the cart, the rule 1 should apply
This means that you can buy 2x + 2y + 2z and get $150 off and the rule 1 shouldn't be applied
If you buy 2x + 2y + 1z you should get $125 off ($50 from rule 1 + $75 from rule 2)

Thank you

Comment: Can anyone help? At least for #1?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

the question was about this particular case. And the answer doesn't really help

Conditions
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
If total quantity  greater than  0  for a subselection of items in cart matching ALL  of these conditions: 
SKU  is  x

If total quantity  greater than  0  for a subselection of items in cart matching ALL  of these conditions: 
SKU  is  y

This will remove $50 for each of these items in the cart.
Let's say 2x and 1y. I get a discount of $150 instead of $50

Thanks

Comment: Have it take the $50 off the cart not the items.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add a shopping cart price rule and under the conditions part use "If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE"
and for the conditions put total quantity for sku x is greater than 0 and another one for sku y 
Then add the discount to the actions part of the shopping cart price rule.

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score -1):

I created a rule for each case (x+y, x+z, y+z...) Not very optimized but at least it worked